# performing just one iteration of a function using python

Tags: python, pandas, break

I have a function, but for testing purposes, I would like to run it just once and not have it iterate through the whole dataset.

My code looks as follows:

```
def issue_ago(date):
    today = datetime.today()
    if type(date) == str:
        date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        print date
        epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
        diff = today - date
        date = diff.days /365.25
        return date
    else:
        return date
```

I am then running this across a column in my dataset to convert a date using the below code. The column in my dataset is a series:

```
data['Issue_Ago'] = data['issue_created_on'].apply(issue_ago)
```

I was considering using a ˋbreakˋ clause but that it seems requires use of a ˋforˋ loop.

What would be recommendations on the best way to do this?

Comment: What iteration are you talking about?

Comment: the easiest way i can think of, is just give it a small dataset to run on. No extra code needed. Also, are you using this with `pandas`?

Comment: Since the posted function is not iterating through any data, your question does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @MattR Yea using a small dataset is a pretty obvious good idea. Is there anyway to do this programmatically however?

Comment: @Taylrl, why does testing a function have to be programmatic? would you not only be testing it a few times? Perhaps all of the commenters, including myself, are missing something. You may want to edit your question if we are. edit: yeah, since you are using pandas use `iloc` or `loc` (you have a post on this) to filter on a small dataset. In any programming or data analysis - you don't always have to think hard, just smart. Don't make too much work for yourself :)

Comment: @MattR You are quite right. What I am trying to do more generally (that you are also quite right, I haven't really explained) is to understand why when the column 'Issue_created_on' is a Series, theˋtype(date) == str:ˋ statement returns as ˋTrueˋ. Each element in the series is a ˋstrˋ but I as I understand it, I have applied the function to the ˋSeriesˋ.

Comment: @Taylrl, I'd go ahead and edit your question to get to the bottom of this, I have a feeling the title may need to be changed as well. But the [`apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function takes your function `issue_ago` and *applies* it to every row in the series `issue_created_on`. Check the bottom of that documentation as well - you may need to use `map` or `transform` to get to what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as i can guess you just want to test wether you function is working correctly or not on a subset of the dataframe ( which might be enormous). So I would say you could take a random sample and apply your function on that one. like

```
df_test = data.sample(frac = 0.1) # could also use n= instead 
df_test['Issue_Ago'] = df_test['issue_created_on'].apply(issue_ago)
```

Then you could compare if it is running into errors and if the result is the one you were looking for. 
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just apply it to a portion of the DataFrame:

```
data.head()['issue_created_on'].apply(issue_ago)
# or
data.head(1)['issue_created_on'].apply(issue_ago)
```